# nginx: try_files not finding static files, falling back to PHP

Tags: nginx

Relevant configuration:

```
location /myapp {
    root /home/me/myapp/www;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /myapp/index.php?url=$uri&$args;

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include       /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    }
}
```

I absolutely have a file `foo.html` in `/home/me/myapp/www` but when I browse to `/myapp/foo.html` it is handled by PHP, the final fallback in the `try_files` list.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

If you browse to `/myapp/foo.html`, Nginx checks the file at `/home/me/myapp/www/myapp/foo.html`. When it doesn't find it there, it goes on to the fallback in the `try_files` list.

If you need Nginx to check the file at `/home/me/myapp/www/foo.html`, then you'd need to use `alias` instead of `root`, in your use case. Here's the solution...

```
location /myapp {
    alias /home/me/myapp/www;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /myapp/index.php?url=$uri&$args;

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include       /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    }
}
```

Note that there is a [longstanding bug](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) that `alias` and `try_files` don't work together. Also, note that using `alias` may break other parts of your configuration, such as PHP processing!

Comment: argh, so  basically I should just use Apache.

Comment: @WellsOliver: yep, if you want to *have* to use much heavier hardware for the same kind of lifting. I prefer servers that have evolved to solve the C10K problem, though. YMMV. Nginx has its shortcomings (as do lighttpd and Apache and essentially any software), but Apache doesn't beat Nginx when it comes to efficiency.